# Storing and searching maps in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, performance, amazon-web-services, maps, amazon-dynamodb

So I have been trying to store Java Maps in DynamoDB but have not found any success.

I keep getting the following error

```
requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted
```

Now I could create a converter and just convert the map to a string, but that seems like a lot of work so not sure if I am missing something, seen as I do not need to do that for a List for example.

Also, if I can actually succeed in storing a map, does Dynamo offer ways of searching for a particular map key or value.
For example, let's say one of the columns in the Dynamo table is a Map, can i say execute a query to give me back all entires were everyone > 30 ran the marathon in less than 5 minutes? Or maybe I need a different approach for this...

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB records are literally maps, so yes you can definitely store and search maps in DynamoDB. [It looks like](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1193) if your map isn't of `<String, AttributeValue>` then you need to provide a custom converter. You wouldn't convert the entire map to a string, you would convert the map to a `Map<String, AttributeValue>`

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could consider is 
`@DynamoDBDocument`. Basically it means instead of using a map you are using an object (but translates to a Map with different data types in Dynamo)

Check this link for an example
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/331